# Service layer design, where to check permissions, and how to handle UI layer

Tags: java, oop, spring-mvc, soa

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(@Valid ProductForm productForm, BindingResult bindingResult,
                           HttpServletRequest request) {
    SessionContext sessionContext = (SessionContext) request.getAttribute("sessionContext");

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("products/new");
    mav.addObject("errors", bindingResult.getAllErrors());
    mav.addObject("productForm", productForm);

    int newProductId = -1;

    if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

        List<Product> products = productService.find...(...);
        if (products != null...) {
            bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("Products", "..."));
        }

        // only try and create if no errors so far
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            newProductId = productService.create(..., productForm);
            if (newProductId <= 0) {
                bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("Products", "..."));
            }
        }
    }

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return mav;
    }


    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/products/show/" + newProductId);
}
```

So the above describes the UI side of things (using Spring MVC).

Now, how should I be designing the service layer, so in this example the ProductServiceImpl has a create method that will will create the product and persist it in the database.

I have to check for permissions, based on the users role etc.

I could to this in the UI layer by first checking if the user has permissions to create a product:

```
if(permissionService.hasPermission(.....)) {
  newProductId = productService.create(....)
}
```

But this ties this logic into the UI layer, I think it should be in the create method itself:

```
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

  @Autowired
  PermissionService permissionService;

  ..

  @Override
  public int create(...., final ProductForm productForm) {

     boolean canCreateProduct = productService.hasPermissions(.....);

     if(canCreateProduct) {
       Product product = ..... (productForm);
       productDao.save(product);
       return product.getId();
     }   
  }
}
```

**But the problem I can't understand is if I put the permission check in ProductServiceImpl.create method, how do I report back to the UI layer that you don't have permissions to do this?**

If you say I should throw an exception, then my UI layer looks very cluttered as I will have so many exceptions to handle based on the various checks I need to perform.

What should I be doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permission checks like this should/could be done with AOP, through means of a mechanism like [CDI's interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/interceptors.html). Spring has method interceptors serving the same purpose (see [AOP in Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html)). Throwing an exception in case of insufficient rights is the correct approach.

That said, I see your problem, but the common solution is quite simple: Your UI receives the rights of its user post-login (or retrieves them through some `UserService`). Using this info, you adjust the operations you expose in the UI. In your example, you do not display the operation for creating a new product if the user is not allowed to do so.

You will probably still want to handle the exception though (let's say in case a user's rights are modified server-side in the meantime) and display an error if it occurs.

Comment: I'm not well versed in AOP, and this application is pretty light in terms of these sort of checks so I'd rather put it in the service layer or UI etc.

Comment: As you suggested in your question already, putting the check in the `create` method and throwing an exception upon a failed check is the best alternative imo.

Comment: ok this is starting to make sense, I perform permission checks to prevent the page from loading in the first place, but if they try and bypass if I throw an exception it will be fine since it will be a rarer case right?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I mean!